# On the absence of predicate verbs in clauses

Tags: verbes, syntaxe, attributs

> [On dit les Français portés sur la gaudriole et obnubilés par la
>   "chose", mais ils feraient presque figure de pères la rigueur si on
>   les compare à leurs voisins... allemands.](http://www.lepoint.fr/monde/les-allemands-raffolent-du-porno-sur-la-toile-30-07-2013-1709812_24.php)

In this clause, shouldn't there have been: *les Français **sont** portés sur la gaudriole [...]* (=the French are all about sex)? Why is the predicate absent? Is its absence part of a certain syntactical rule?

*portés* and *obnubilés*, if taken on their own, seem to me to be adjectives rather than verbs as the predicate of the main clause.

(I'm also not sure if the main clause is only *les Français portés sur la gaudriole et obnubilés par la "chose"* or *On dit les Français portés sur la gaudriole et obnubilés par la "chose"*.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick primer:

As you note yourself *portés sur la chose* and *obnubilés par la "chose"* are regular adjectival phrases that are connected to *Les Français*. However, they do not use the common *épithète* or *attribut du sujet* constructions.

What we have here is termed an *attribut du **complément*** (by opposition to *attribut du sujet*). It is analogous to saying *J'ai baptisé mon chien Fido.*, where Fido is an attribut du complément *chien*.

What the sentence means is something like

> The French *are said* to be obsessed with [...]

Which is quite different from your proposed *Les Français sont portés sur la gaudriole* ("The French **are obsessed** with [...]").

This sentence is somewhat hard to translate in English, but only because of the awkwardness of fitting a generic/impersonal pronoun as the subject in English (and the fact this particular construction sounds more natural with nouns than adjectives), but consider:

> They called me a pervert.

Comment: SVP, pourriez-vous insérer dans votre réponse les équivalents anglais de tous les termes de grammaire, tels que *attribut du sujet*, *attribut du complément* ?

Answer (score 6):

The verb you are looking for is “*dit*”. As per the [Dictionnaire de l'Académie, 9](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/dire)

> ★II. Par ext. Faire connaître, exprimer, avec des nuances particulières.
>   ☆1. Affirmer, prétendre

Here, its arguments are “*les Français*” and “*portés sur la gaudriole et obnubilés par la "chose"*”, the latter being an adjectival syntagme, where the past participles *porté* and *obnubilé* are used as transitive adjectives. This syntagme could be replaced by any simple adjective

> *On dit les Français cannibales, mais…*

The fact that this syntagme is long and contains transitive entities changes nothing as it is still only an adjectival syntagme, and doesn't need any verb. Here is a quite informal (because I couldn't be bothered to make it X') and non-expanded tree of the clause

[image: Syntactic tree for the main clause]

The predicate is “X are said to be Y”, where Y is “*portés sur la gaudriole et obnubilés par la "chose"*” and everything is fine, yay!

Comment: Doesn’t need any verb and *must* have none. If one wishes to use a verb, they should write *On dit **que** les Français sont portés sur la gaudriole*.