# Qu'est-ce qui distingue un « attribut du sujet », d'un « épithète » ou d'un « référent » ?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, comparaison-de-langues

Quelles sont les différences entre : *attribut* (nm) du sujet, *épithète* (nf), et *référent* (nm) ?

Avant tout, je ne me mêle que des différences pratiques envers la langue française et la peine de la parler couramment, et non pas des différences à propos de la linguistique. Je suis tombé sur deux d'entre eux sur [On the absence of predicate verbs in clauses](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7126/on-the-absence-of-predicate-verbs-in-clauses).

Par conséquent, veuillez détailler les différences pragmatiques tout d'abord avant d'autres trucs.

Par ailleurs, je suis conscient que *attribute* & *epithet* & *referent* existent en anglais. Si les idées en travers des deux langues sont les mêmes, n'hésitez pas à en discourir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Attribut* et *épithète* sont des termes lié à la syntaxe de l'adjectif.

L'*adjectif attribut* est connecté au nom ou au pronom qu'il qualifie (généralement, mais pas toujours le sujet, ainsi que le note la question à laquelle tu fais référence) par un verbe. Le plus commun de ces verbes est *être*. Syntaxiquement, cet adjectif fait partie du groupe verbal (le *prédicat*) et ne peut que très rarement être supprimé sans violer la syntaxe de la phrase. L'attribut est une fonction syntaxique que certaines autres classes grammaticales (notamment le nom et le pronom) peuvent aussi remplir.

> Cet homme est généreux.

L'*adjectif épithète* est directement subordonné au nom ou au pronom. C'est un membre du groupe (pro)nominal, et il est généralement possible de le supprimer sans trop affecter la syntaxe de la phrase. Contrairement à l'attribut, je ne crois pas que d'autres types de mots remplissent la fonction grammaticale d'épithète.

> Un homme généreux fait preuve de générosité.

*Référent* est un terme de linguistique plus technique (il n'est pas, **à ma connaissance**, lié à la syntaxe de l'adjectif). Il est lié à la relation sémantique entre la langue et le monde réel. Le référent est le terme qui, dans la description de cette relation, s'applique à un objet/être le plus souvent physique et réel dont il est actuellement question.

---

Quant à la question concernant l'anglais, [Wikipedia en anglais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective#Types_of_use) parle respectivement d'*attributive adjective* et de *predicative adjective*. (On y mentionne aussi l'*absolute adjective*, qui est souvent considérée en français comme une variante de l'épithète, dite *en apposition* ou *épithète détachée*.)

*Epithet* et *attribute* désignent chacun en anglais des concepts différents de leurs faux-amis français, mais *referent* s'emploie à peu près dans le même sens (je n'ose être trop catégorique).

Comment: Plussoyé.  Je tiens à vous exprimer ma gratitude.